# What is a bit pattern?

Tags: java, variables, design-patterns, bit, scjp

I'm reading a book at it cites the following:

> With primitive variables, an assignment of one variable to another means the contents (bit pattern) of one variable are copied into another...The contents of a reference variable are a bit pattern...

Please help me understand what 'bit pattern' means here. Is that another way of saying the memory address of a variable?

For example, what could the bit patterns look like for the following two variables

1. int x;
2. TimeClass time;
3. Integer y;

So, for example if "int x = 4" and that 4 resides at memory address X77348 then what gets copied to the other reference? 00000100 (which is 4 in binary)? or the X77348

Comment: In which book was this mentioned?

Comment: SCJP Java 6, Kathy Sierra, Bert Bates

Comment: A bit pattern is simply 1s and 0s. Any variable is simply that. So is a pointer/reference. Skip over that explanation and chalk it up to a statement of the obvious.

Comment: So it would be the binary representation of the primitive variable that gets copied? i.e. 00000100. But how about for object references?

Comment: Just remember *With primitive variables, an assignment of one variable to another means the contents (bit pattern) of one variable are copied into another* is **true** and the contents of a reference variable are the memory address of these actual contents to which this memory address is pointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the memory address of the primitive variables.  The **contents** of the memory address of the primitive variable.

Likewise, with a reference it's the **contents** of the memory address of the reference variable.  (Remember that behind the scenes a Java reference is essentially a pointer.  So the "bit pattern" with respect to a reference is that pointer (which points to wherever on the heap the object lives)).